# Django-Q does not kill old threads and CPU raises 100%

Tags: python, django

I'm deploying Django-Q on a production server using a systemd service like below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Django-q management service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/api
$e/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env/bin/python manage.py qcluster                      
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Every time qcluster starts a thread (about 8.5% CPU), the old ones does not die and CPU raises 100%.

PD: The problem is also happening if I run qcluster directly on the terminal.

Comment: I'd imagine the tasks you're running are leaking something.

Comment: just sending an email, tested in local environment and works perfectly